# in kotlin, how to pass back a MutableList where the destination expects a List

Tags: android, list, inheritance, kotlin

having a hashMap with List as value defined:

```
     private var mMap: HashMap<String, List<DataStatus>>? = null
```

having a function return a hashMap but with the value of MutableList

```
     fun getDataStatus(response: JSONObject?): HashMap<String, MutableList<DataStatus>> {

          return HashMap<String, MutableList<AccountStatusAlert>>()
     }
```

when pass the result to the hashMap expecting List it got error:

```
     mMap = getDataStatus(resp) //<== got error
```

got error:

```
Error:(81, 35) Type mismatch: inferred type is HashMap<String, 
MutableList<DataStatus>> but HashMap<String, List<DataStatus>>? was expected
```

Comment: As far as I know, you'll have to cast the expression to `HashMap<String, List<DataStatus>>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two solutions depending on your needs.

**Cast it**

Considering that `MutableList` is a subclass of `List`, you can cast it. There's only a problem here: you will lose immutability. If you cast the `List` back to `MutableList`, you can modify its content.

```
mMap = getDataStatus(repo) as HashMap<String, List<String>>
```

**Convert it**

In order to maintain immutability on the list, you have to convert each `MutableList` to an immutable `List`:

```
mMap = HashMap<String, List<String>>()
getDataStatus(repo).forEach { (s, list) ->
    mMap?.put(s, list.toList())
}
```

In this case, if you try to modify the content of a list inside `mMap`, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: @lannyf Thanks to have pointed out your doubts, I've edited my answer using a better explanation

Answer (score 1):

If you do not plan to put new items in the map after it was returned to you, just declare your variable having a more permissive type:

```
// prohibits calling members that take List<DataStatus> as a parameter,
// so you can store a HashMap with values of any List subtype, 
// for example of MutableList
private var mMap: HashMap<String, out List<DataStatus>>? = null
```

or

```
// prohibits calling mutating methods
// List<DataStatus> already has 'out' variance
private var mMap: Map<String, List<DataStatus>>? = null
```

If you for some reason need that variable to have exactly that type, then you need to convert or upcast values in the returned map:

```
mMap = getDataStatus(resp).mapValuesTo(HashMap()) { (_, v) -> v as List<DataStatus> }
```

Answer (score 0):

One great solution is:

```
private var mMap: Map<String, List<DataStatus>>? = null // Do you 
//really need to have object with interface of HashMap? I don't think so..
mMap = getDataStatus(resp).mapValues { it.value.toList() } 
// add as HashMap<String, List<DataStatus>> if you really need 
//HashMap interface
```

So, using var + nullable types is not recommended when using Kotlin. Maybe you want follows:

```
val mMap = mutableMapOf<String, List<DataStatus>()
```

or immediately:

```
val mMap = getDataStatus(resp).mapValues {
 it.value.toList()
}
```