# Why can I pass a MutableList parameter to class which accept List parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The class CustomAdapter accept a List parameter in Code B, but why can I use Code A create a object of CustomAdapter by passing MutableList parameter ?

**Code A**

```
private lateinit var allList: MutableList<MSetting>

allList=SettingHandler().getListAllSetting().toMutableList()
mCustomAdapter= CustomAdapter(allList)
mRecyclerView.adapter= mCustomAdapter
```

**Code B**

```
class CustomAdapter (val backupItemList: List<MSetting>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
}
```

Comment: You should have read about Java Polymorphism it is also applicable to Kotlin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in kotlin, how to pass back a MutableList where the destination expects a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650079/in-kotlin-how-to-pass-back-a-mutablelist-where-the-destination-expects-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source of `MutableList`, you will see that `MutableList` extends `List`, which is why you can pass `MutableList` to functions that expect a `List`:

```
public interface MutableList<E> : List<E>
```

The `MutableList` merely adds new functionality to the `List` type, making it mutable.